# High Charts candlestick and volume pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using HighCharts in my appliation.

Please have a look the below URL:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.6/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/

In that chart there is normal candle stick graph and volume pane are there.

I want to draw volume pane below the range selector of main chart. The problem with that is if we set zoomType:xy i am getting so many issues.

And also the below volume will get reflect when we change the range selector of above main chart.

Give me any idea to complete this task.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the problem is?  What do you mean by "getting so many issues"?  The chart looks fine to me.

Comment: What i want exactly is I want to control the chart from out side container. Like for example inside "container" div the chart is displaying. I have another div which has buttons to control the chart.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wJ7m9/ Does the job?